# how to make a window not moveable in pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to "lock" my interface so a user can not move the window from its position how can I do that?

I only found so far the `QDockWidg` class which can be set to `setFloating(False)`

but how can I do that with my window below?

```
import sys

import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg



class Example(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here


        vlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        heading = qtw.QLabel("wählen")
        self.test_button1 = qtw.QRadioButton("test1")
        self.test_button2 = qtw.QRadioButton("test2")

        self.select_button = qtw.QPushButton("select")

        hlayout.addWidget(self.test_button1)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.test_button1)


        vlayout.addWidget(heading)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.select_button)

        self.setLayout(vlayout)

        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I guess you could set the window flag FramelessWindowHint.

Comment: @Heike thanks it worked `self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Comment: @Heike do you know why my window closses if i add this line ?                                       `elif self.radiobutton.isChecked(): `                                                                                                                                                                                       
                   ` self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Comment: @HoboCoder what is `radiobutton`?

Comment: @eyllanesc its a `QRadioButton`

Comment: QRadioButtons are `test_button1` and  `test_button2` in your code

Comment: @eyllanesc my mistake here is the code [gist](https://gist.github.com/JosephCurvin/3d6213c37903b392b5075b7dca1c457a)

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to "lock" the window if the radio button is selected

Answer (score 0):

For example, connect the signal `toggled` to `self.test_button1`.

> [signal]void QAbstractButton::toggled(bool checked)
>
> This signal is emitted whenever a checkable button changes its state. checked is true if the button is checked, or false if the button is unchecked.

In the `on_off_func` slot, check the status of `self.test_button1`
and set the desired `Flag`. After that, be sure to call `self.show ()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg



class Example(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here


        vlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        heading = qtw.QLabel("wählen")
        self.test_button1 = qtw.QRadioButton("test1")
        self.test_button1.toggled.connect(self.on_off_func)          # +
        self.test_button2 = qtw.QRadioButton("test2")

        self.select_button = qtw.QPushButton("select")

        hlayout.addWidget(self.test_button1)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.test_button2)

        vlayout.addWidget(heading)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.select_button)

        self.setLayout(vlayout)

        self.show()

    def on_off_func(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.Window)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]